# Flutter Floor Database cannot access in Background mode Android

Tags: android, flutter, floor

I am trying to store data locally in my flutter application using flutter **floor** plugin.

When my application is in foreground i am successfully able to create and initialize my database properly.

But when my application is in Background then i am getting Error as mention below.

Error:

```
 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
```

Please help me on this issue.